# *** NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClass in Rails 3.2 with Rspec in controllers spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2, rspec-rails

I have configured Rspec Ruby 2.0.0-p0 and Rails 3.2.14 configuration is perfect I'm sure on that but when I try to run rake spec:controllers it gaves me below error on every request action written in spec example -

```
*** NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClass
```

I have written specs for controllers before but never come across such situation, help me If any one has fixed same issue....

Here is my spec and error stack

```
describe UsersController do

  before (:each) do
    @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    sign_in @user
  end

  describe "GET 'index'" do

    it "should be successful" do
      get 'index'
      response.should be_success
    end

  end
  describe "GET 'show'" do

    it "should be successful" do
      get :show, :id => @user.id
      response.should be_success
    end

    it "should find the right user" do
      get :show, :id => @user.id
      assigns(:user).should == @user
    end

  end

end
```

Here is result -

```
Failures:

  1) UsersController GET 'index' should be successful
     Failure/Error: get 'index'
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClass
     # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:13:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) UsersController GET 'show' should be successful
     Failure/Error: get :show, :id => @user.id
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClass
     # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:21:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  3) UsersController GET 'show' should find the right user
     Failure/Error: get :show, :id => @user.id
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClass
     # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:26:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.4741 seconds
3 examples, 3 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:12 # UsersController GET 'index' should be successful
rspec ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:20 # UsersController GET 'show' should be successful
rspec ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:25 # UsersController GET 'show' should find the right user

Randomized with seed 19701
```

My factory is -

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    first_name 'Test User'
    last_name 'Last name'
    email 'example@example.com'
    password 'changeme'
    password_confirmation 'changeme'
    company 'RR'
    confirmed_at Time.now
  end
end
```

We need company name mandatory to create register user.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
       before_filter :authenticate_user!
      #authorize_resource 

     def index
        @users = User.all
      end

      def show
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
      end
 end
```

here I have added two methods for test in user controller.

Same thing I tried with demo example that works great but not in my project....
Thanks

Comment: Please share your spec, code and full stack trace.

Comment: Hi Graeme please check updated question for more detail. thanks

Comment: Please also share your user factory and model.

Comment: I think the problem in your controller. And even more: you have the same error for `index` and `show` actions, it looks like the problem in common `before_filter`. Anyway - post you controller

Comment: Please check I have added controller as well.

Comment: Thank you to all, finally got fixed please check my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using devise gem for authentication then you need to specify the devise mapping in controller test cases.

Replace the code in the before(:each) block with below code

```
@user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
@request.env['devise.mapping'] = Devise.mappings[:user]
sign_in @user
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I fixed issue, it comes due to authenticate_user! method in application controller which inherits to every controllers -

```
 prepend_before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => [:not_authenticated]
```

I have added below module to fix issue occurs due to this devise method -(support/controllers_helpers.rb)

```
module ControllerHelpers
    def sign_in(user = double('user'))
      if user.nil?
        request.env['warden'].stub(:authenticate!).
          and_throw(:warden, {:scope => :user})
        controller.stub :current_user => nil
      else
        request.env['warden'].stub :authenticate! => user
        controller.stub :current_user => user
      end
    end
  end
```

finally include above module in spec_helper.rb file

```
 config.include ControllerHelpers, :type => :controller
```

Got running all controllers specs.

Cheers!!!

[more info](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Stub-authentication-in-controller-specs)